# Dividing variables by a certain value in SPSS and store it into the original variable

Tags: spss

So this should be super easy, but I'm hitting a wall nevertheless.
I have a set of variables "Time in seconds day 1" to "Time in seconds day n" and I want to convert them to contain time in minutes. As the dataset is already very large though I want to just convert the original variables from Var_1 to Var_n by dividing all of them by 60. While it is obvious that I need some sort of

For i in (Var_1 to Var_n) transform i = i/60

logic, I can't find how to do this in SPSS, as recode apparently requires defining every value individually. I could of course load the whole dataset into R or Python as a workaround it's super frustrating I can't work out how to perform this simple operation in SPSS.

Comment: look up "do repeat" and "loop" - both should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's already helpful as I didn't know these functions before - looking these up would have  been the second step. What the real issue is though: How do I make SPSS do the v = v/60 part? It does not work on its own, it does not work as recode v1 (v1= v1/60) or recode v1(else= v1/60)- what do I need to put in the loop?

Comment: All you need is `compute v=v/60.`

Comment: Alright, thank you. Got so stuck on that recode I forgot you could overwrite a variable with compute.

Comment: @eli-k would compute v=v/60. return an integer or a float? and in case it returns an integer how can it return a float?

Comment: That's not an issue in SPSS - the result will be stored with all the decimals. You can control how many decimalts you want to see in the data view with `formats` command.